# Why json string from obj.getAttribute doesn't want to parse?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsn=getAttr(ref,"json-data").toString();
console.log(jsn); //{test: true,stringtest:"hallo"}. it's OK.
JSON.parse(jsn); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s, line: line with JSON.parse;
```

I think `JSON.parse` does something not right with this data.. I tried to remove `stringtest:"hallo"` - no result... PS: also I think that I do something wrong then I have asked this question

At the first time I tried `JSON.parse("{"+jsn+"}");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not properly formatted, as your object keys must be surrounded by quotation marks. The following will work:

```
var jsn = '{"test": true, "stringtest": "hallo"}';
JSON.parse(jsn);
```

Edit: The RFC4627, which specifies JSON format, states:

> 2.2.  Objects
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
>   surrounding zero or more **name/value pairs** (or members).  **A name is a
>
>   string**.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
>   from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
>   name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.
>
> ```
>   object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
>   end-object
>
>   member = string name-separator value
> ```

As you can see, JSON objects are composed of name/value pairs, where a name is a string. Again, the RFC says:

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C 
>   family of programming languages.  **A string begins and ends with
>
>   quotation marks**.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
>   quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
>   quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
>   through U+001F).
>
> string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
>
> **quotation-mark = %x22      ; "**

So, according to the RFC, keys must be surrounded by double quotes, not single one. Still, I guess some parsers may be more tolerant and accept both of them, but I'd stick to the standard.

Comment: I think it was just the habit from JS object `var obj={som:'qwe'};`, I think. :) Thnx.